# webapp2 - route for hanlder with params

Tags: routes, webapp2

I have route defined in this way:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/v/<link:\d+>', handler=View),
```

Now I want to create another Route which will be for specific `link`. Something like:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/test', handler=View('specific link')),
```

Is there a way to create route in this way? Or should I create new handler and in this handler call another one with predefined `link`? If yes how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to provide dictionary with defaults arguments to RequestHandler:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/test', handler=View, defaults={'link': 'default_link'}),
```